# Suggestions on how to design a sql table to store menu item modifiers?

Tags: sql

I've been searching for hours but I guess I can't find the right terms. Say you were making an online ordering system with 6 products and wanted to allow modifiers (some swap ingredients, some add extra to the cost, etc).

My idea right now is to create the products table with the 6 main items. Then I'd create a table for each item that includes the modifiers only for that item.

I'm trying to figure out how to get them stored in a SQL database, and able to be displayed as a receipt.

For Example:

```
Order # 123512353

##### Item 1 #####        
Hamburger       $8
---Add Cheese + $1
---No Ketchup       

##### Item 2 #####
Hamburger       $8
---No Lettuce

TOTAL          $17
```

I plan on using sessions and to allow for up to 12 items per ticket. I just can't figure out how to associate the item modifiers to the items on a per ticket basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your model should have 3 tables:

Products

Modifications

Orders

Products is your master list of 6 items (ex: Hamburger, Salad)

Modifications is your 1:N list of potential modifiers (ex: Hamburger:Cheese, Hamburger:Pickles, Salad:Ranch)

Orders is your transaction list (ex: Order 1:Hamburger:Cheese, Order1:Hamburger:Pickles, Order1:Salad:Ranch, Order2:Salad:Italian Dressing, Order3:Hamburger:NULL)

I know the formatting isn't great, but hopefully this makes sense.

edit: You can also take it one step further and break out the Order and Details. In that case, you would have a OrderHeader and OrderDetails table, where the OrderDetails table references back to the Products and Modifications, and the OrderHeader contains the header level info (Customer, Order number, etc.)